# android ArrayAdapter loads slow with 1000 elements

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView with An ArrayAdapter. When I instantiate the adapter with up to 300 elements it's fine, But if a load it with 1000 elements it's very slow, it takes 5 seconds on a Nexus 4..

Now I simply initialize it with An arraylist and call setListAdapter. 
Is there a way to load it in background?

Thank you

Comment: does adapter have images? consider to add pagination.

Comment: can you post your adapter class here?

Comment: Show a Spinner while loading, you can load data in an AsyncTask to fetch your data in the doInBackground and use the Pre- and PostExecute to show and dismiss your spinner.

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo sometimes asynchronous is not needed if the user need to view only first page...wt do you say??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good option to avoid this problem is `pagination` in listadapter..

you can have better `userinterface` and  `performance` to your app by this..

there are tons of tutorials and sample codes to teach you..

few are

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Comment: Yeah, thank you for this, I will implement pagination in the future so it's ok. I see someone saying to load data in background, in asyncTask, but it's possibile to call setListAdapter in the onBackground? because I think it's that method that takes many time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is good option. But before that can you check the process of populating 1000 records, it may be time consuming. I don't think, Android ListView loads all 1000 elements in one short.